# loading dynamic content boxes using JQuery and Dropdown Change event

Tags: jquery, html

I am a bit off on Jquery. I think I know my way but I am having trouble understanding the approach I have to take.

I have to create something similar to http://www.salesforce.com/customers/

There will be 2 dropdowns and a list of boxes that shows customers.

selecting a dropdown may produce some no. of content boxes (as shown in the link above) tagged to record., also changing one dropdown will make other dropdown value to default.

I  am actually using MOSS 2007. I wil try my best to emit the html out in such a way that boxes are shown, but i would like to select the content boxes based on the selection of dropdown without doing a postback. which means i would have load all the content boxes first and then show and hide div's that are tagged to the dropdown value.

Can somebody explain me in an html and a jquery way, how to achieve that.

I can't use ajax to load json as MOSS 2007 does not support JSON and we have some restriction in using the web services. i have to fetch all the customers initially. I understand the load , but we will have a small subset of it as default when the page loads.

Any example would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Well basically in pseudo-code, it will be: `if select box equals 1 then images equals 1,2,3,4,5` `if select box equals 2 then images equals 6,7,8,9,10`.  It's not really complicated but enough that not too many people are going to want to write the whole thing for you.  You can change values and divs and images in jquery using `.change()`.   Try some things out, look for other examples on here, and then ask again if you have some questions by making an edit to this post.

Comment: In fact the first one that came up under Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760920/jquery-dropdown-loading-content?rq=1

Comment: Ok Thanks.
Was trying to understand how to tag images with multiple tags,  and then probably use jquery selectors.

Comment: Look at how to add images to an array in javascript.  Or a different way to do it is to have 5 divs, with each div containing the images you'd like to contain for each select item.  Then on select change, hide all other divs and show that corresponding div.